# AWS S3 Pre-Signed URL "the provided token has expired" error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, token, pre-signed-url

I set the pre-signed url's expiration to 36 hours (sts max time), but I get the error "the provided token has expired".

The credentials are being supplied with the ec2 instance profile and the STS temporary accesskey issued starts with ASIA.

I am generating presigned-url with JAVA.

In the local environment (accesskey starting with AKIA), we confirmed that the pre-signed url normally expires after 36 hours without token expiration.

Please reply if you know how to solve the token has expired error.

Comment: EC2 credentials are not valid for 36 hours and therefore a presigned url they create cannot be valid for that long. If you need a presigned url with that expiration you would need long lived credentials.

Comment: The official documentation states that using the sts policy, pre-signed urls can be maintained for up to 36 hours.

What are long-lived credentials?

Comment: IAM user access + secret keys are long-lived, everything else can at max be valid for 12 hours.